# background gradient not working in chrome (works in firefox)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have linear background gradient in browser. It works in FF but does not work in Chrome. My CSS looks as follows:

```
  /* works in FF */

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(40, 40, 40) 0px, rgb(10, 10, 10) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;


  /* Not working in chrome */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(40, 40, 40) 0px, rgb(10, 10, 10) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: Note: in the future use the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/), it rocks. From the generator , [example of your code working in chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/WL9wL/).

Comment: thanks much.... I will make it an answer and accept soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my comment, in the future use the [Ultimate CSS Gradient Generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/).

You can also upload your own **CSS** to generate the *browser compatibility style*.

From your **CSS**:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , rgb(40, 40, 40) 0px, rgb(10, 10, 10) 100%) repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
```

The *generator* outputs:

```
background: #282828; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #282828 0px, #0a0a0a 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0px,#282828), color-stop(100%,#0a0a0a)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #282828 0px,#0a0a0a 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #282828 0px,#0a0a0a 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #282828 0px,#0a0a0a 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right, #282828 0px,#0a0a0a 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#282828', endColorstr='#0a0a0a',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WL9wL/)